# GCP Dedicated Interconnect MTU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/dedicated/configuring-onprem-routers

I switched the GCP Dedicated Interconnect.
What I need to configure is the onprem-router.
However, the MTU value of my switch is the minimum value of 1500 although the Guide has an MTU value of 1440.
Is the GCP router only different because it is a virtual router of SDN?
It doesn't matter if you set the MTU for the onprem-router at 1500?

Answer (score 0):

It is [best practice](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/dedicated/configuring-onprem-routers#configuration_guidelines) for the MTU of Cloud Router (1440 bytes) matches the on-prem switch's MTU for preserving the packets in most efficient way.  If this setting is not made, communications (packets) may be disabled or lost.

Most recent switches' minimum MTU starts with a little over 1400 bytes. Check your switch brand and version to see the range of MTU supported by the switch: if the minimum is indeed 1500 or if it was [configured](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-0_2_EX/int_hw_components/configuration_guide/b_int_152ex_2960-x_cg/b_int_152ex_2960-x_cg_chapter_0110.pdf) to 1500. The MTUs need to match for most efficient use of Cloud Interconnect.